# HTML/CSS - Navigation

Tags: html, css

So I want to create a navigation bar like we see on most of the sites at the moment.
How it looks like: 1 middle area, with 2 spacings (left and right). Then you see a logo on the left of the 'middle area' and the navigation on the right. 
But I don't know how to do that exactly. Can someone help me to setup a grid?

Many thanks!

Comment: you might wanna do something like https://jsfiddle.net/link2pk/7uqvpc60/1/

Comment: @link2pk Yes! Thankyou so much! And when I want to maken the wrapper on the same outline?

Comment: you can wrap the nav inside a div or section or body like https://jsfiddle.net/link2pk/7uqvpc60/2/

Comment: @link2pk This is what I mean, thankyou!

Comment: SO is here to answer questions about code and markup you wrote but it is not here to write code for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.main-nav {
  background-color: #ffe;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.main-nav ul {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <nav class="main-nav">
    <div class="container">
      <a href="">Logo</a>
      <ul>
        <li>about</li>
        <li>team</li>
        <li>countact us</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <section>
    <div class="container">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Architecto possimus aspernatur atque, dolorum, alias aliquam animi et omnis non dolor cupiditate nostrum minus, error voluptatem, ab cum dicta repudiandae sequi.</p>
    </div>

  </section>
</body>
```